# Magento Global Special Price - Create or Update - HTTP Request

Tags: magento, magento2

**Problem:** I would like to update the global special price of a product in Magento using a `HTTP` `POST` or `PUT` request.

[image: Product Special Price]

Whilst I've seen the endpoint `/V1/products/special-price` in the [docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/), this is per store and not global.

Which endpoint should I send to, with what data?

**Use Cases:**

1. I'll be creating a whole new product, with a special price included at the start
2. I'll be updating an existing product with a new special price
3. I'll be deleting the special price from a product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for scheduling an update. To make it **global**, I set the `store_id` to 0.

```
  {
      "prices": [
        {
          "price": 45.00,
          "store_id": 0,
          "sku": "virtualProductTest",
          "price_from": "2023-01-13 08:43:00",
          "price_to": "2024-10-16 22:30:45",
          "extension_attributes": {}
        }
      ]
    }
```